# How to test Exceptions with ActivityTestCase or InstrumentationTestCase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, junit4

I'm creating some Junit Tests with Android Studio 1.2.2. This is my TestClass. It extends from ActivityTestCase (or InstrumentationTestCase).

```
public class TypeTest extends ActivityTestCase 
{
    TypesMeth typesMeth = new TypesMeth();

    public void testTypes() 
    {
        typesMeth.setValue((short) 1000000);
        assertEquals(exception, typesMeth.getValue());
    }
}
```

The parameter must be short. So the range is from -32768 to 32767.

If I pass a value of 1000000 it should throw an exception and the test should be passed.

How can I check that? Something like: `assertExceptionIsThrown(true, typesMeth.getValue());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classical JUnit 4 you would add some annotation before your testcase

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void myUnitTest() {
   ...
}
```

As far as I know there are no annotation in Android which support this, so you need to do it in a pre JUnit 4 way with try and catch

```
try {
  doSomethingThatShouldThrow();
  fail("Should have thrown Exception");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // success
}
```